# Select all rows from 1st table except the first occurrence in 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out a way of selecting all rows from the 1st table except the first occurence in 2nd table when rows are repeating.

For example,

Table1:

```
ABC
ABC
DEF
GHJ
GHJ
```

Table2:

```
ABC
GHJ
```

Expected result (from the first table):

```
ABC
DEF
GHJ
```

So the first ABC and the first GHJ were removed from the first table.

Comment: How do you know which row is "first"?  Right now they just look like duplicates.

Comment: Do the tables have a primary key? Tables behave more like *sets* and not like *lists*. They don't have any ordering.

Comment: What does the second table have to do with anything?

Comment: What if Table1 has 3 occurrences of ABC?  What if Table1 has 2 occurrences of DEF?

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Voting to close.

Comment: You've abstracted this so far that it's virtually meaningless as written, I'm afraid.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense, can you make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `row_number()` to handle this:

```
select t1.*
from (select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.name = t2.name and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
where t2.name is null;
```

Note:  This returns arbitrary names.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is not "first" row in a table, unless a column specifies the ordering.  If you have an ordering in mind, then use that for the `order by`.

Also, this allows duplicates in `t2` and all those will be removed from `t1` if there are any.